# Click event of Typescript with angular not getting object value

Tags: angularjs, templates, typescript

Getting issue with binding value while passing Event parameter from Template to Typescript Button click event.

[image]

See below object, its binding but it not reflecting same to the Typescript controller..

See here that value..
[image]

What it should be reason?

Code:
Get Order template

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>ID  </td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in vm.addNewOrderData track by $index">
        <td><label>{{order.orderID}}</label>  </td>
        <td><label>{{order.orderName}}</label> </td>
        <td><label>{{order.orderPrice}}</label> </td>
        <td><label> <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-model="editobj" ng-click="vm.edit('{{order.orderID}}');">Edit</a></label> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

below is GetOrderController.ts

```
class GetOrderController {
    public vm: any;
    private scope: any;
    public addNewOrderData: any;
    public http: any;
    public location: any;
    constructor($http: any, $scope: any, $location:any) {
        this.scope = $scope;
        this.scope.vm = this;
        this.http = $http;
        this.location = $location;
        $http.get("/api/SampleApi/GetAllOrder").success(
            (data, status) => {
                if (data != "null") {
                    this.addNewOrderData = data;
                }
            }).error((data, status) => {
            this.addNewOrderData = data;
        });
    }

    edit = (id: any): void => {
        debugger;
        var order = { OrderID: id };
        this.http.get("/api/SampleApi/GetOrderById",id
            ).success(
            (data, status) => {
                if (data != "null") {
                    this.location.path('/saveOrder?id=' + order);
                }
                else {
                    alert("No order id found!");
                }

            }).error((data, status) => {

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could share some of the code causing this issue.. as code not as screenshots. :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3SzHw94i

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4ZeVSEAk

Comment: you can use SO's editor to insert and format code. :) looking at the pastebin though I don't see how you actually link the controller with the view.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2NeWnbSn see my email in pastebin.

Comment: @toskv SO's editor not used before.. give me link So editor

Comment: maybe you ought to have a look at SO's help page for editing questions. :) http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131980/discussion-between-abhishek-bhalani-and-toskv).

Comment: @toskv THANK YOU too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-click` shouldn't have `{{}}`(interpolation), do pass direct expression while will get evaluate.

Change

```
ng-click="vm.edit('{{order.orderID}}');"
```

to

```
ng-click="vm.edit(order.orderID);"
```

Comment: i tried. 
it was getting object in controller not value.

Comment: it worked now in the direct object without single quote.